# batch - order and rename files in a directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've looked around, and there are a lot of posts very similar to this but I can't seem to find an answer that will work for what I need.

I have a big list of files with different extensions that I want to rename to numbers. For example

```
SomeFileName1.jpg
SomeFileName2.gif
SomeFileName3.mkv
```

changed to:

```
1.jpg
2.gif
3.mkv
```

I want to keep the extensions the same. Only the name should change to 1,2,3 etc.

A while ago I found some code that renamed all the files (don't have the code anymore), but it renamed them in the wrong order. "SomeFileName3.mkv" became "1.mkv" instead of "3.mkv" for example. I'm not sure if I need to sort them first somehow? I'm not very good at this kind of thing so I could really use some help. Thanks

Comment: How do you decide what order is the right order?

Comment: How are you determining right and wrong order? Is it based on the sort order - or are you're files just getting renamed by removing the "file" from the name. Do you have a better example?

Comment: the names are all very similar and in order, they just have different extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `for` loop to process all files. Use `dir` to sort the files to your needs. Use a counter. Use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) to make the counter work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on /a-d') do (
  set /a count +=1
  ECHO ren "%%a" "!count!%%~xa"
)
```

for more information read `for /?`, `dir /?` and `set /?`

If the output satisfies you, remove the `ECHO` to arm the `ren` command.